# How can I find the specifications and manual for a JVC AV-S280ENT CRT TV?

Tags: crt-monitor, television

I've just "struck gold" (in my world...) by finding an old CRT TV placed in the garbage room of my apartment complex. Didn't think that was ever gonna happen again. Anyway, as logic dictates, I eagerly lugged it home and it turns out to be still working.

However, I simply cannot find any specifications or manual online. I'd like to know which year it was made, exactly how big it is and stuff like that. None of that it says on the back "information plate". Every single search result seems to be for some other model, not even close to this one, even if I quote the product name.

Brand: "**JVC**"

Model: "**AV-S280ENT**"

Manufactured in the UK.

JVC's own websites seem to just be full of broken links, and the "landing page(s)" don't even indicate that it's for the model I have, neither on the page itself or in the URL.

Comment: I don't see any retrocomputing connection.

Comment: @another-dave got a point. Also, independent from the site you're asking  at,  if you're not betting on some jackpot knowing exactly that device, it would be quite helpful to add all available information, like what data is written on the device, what connectors there are and so on, as that can tell a lot about the specs of that device. Plus maybe some pics of those details?